# How do you run Update-Database when your applications starts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, database-migration

Hi this is simple I just need to know how can I run the Update-DataBase command when my application starts. I'm working with a MVC3 application using EF 5.0 Code First Migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Put it in your Global.Asax, in Application_Start:

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(
    new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourContext, YourMigrationsConfig>());
```

Comment: Do I need to do something else with the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion class or just define like in your example?

Comment: It will work out of the box like this, using the migrations you have.  You can also customize it to your liking if you need more advanced functionality

Comment: Hmmm...  For some reason, it's not working for me.  Everything looks right...  I added a migration, the line above executes without error, but nothing happens. The DbMigration code never gets called.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I know I am a late comer but I tried this and it worked perfectly, and can create the database for you if it does not exist. Put this in your `Global.asax`

```
        var migration =  new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourConfig,
            YourMigrationsConfig>();
        var context = new YourContext();
        migration.InitializeDatabase(context);
```